# stringstream not casting integers to string

Tags: c++, ios, macos, casting, stringstream

I've just moved to a new development environment and noticed that my Mac build can no longer use `std::stringstream` to cast integers to string like it used to. My iOS build is fine, but my Mac build isn't and I can't figure out why.

I have this code:

```
int test_value = 4;
std::stringstream val;
val << "foo" << test_value << "bar";
std::cout << "test: " << val.str() << std::endl;
```

On iOS, I get the correct output:

> foo4bar

But on Mac, it fails as soon as it reaches the integer:

> foo

If I cast the integer to a string first, then it works fine:

```
int test_value = 4;
std::stringstream val;
val << "foo" << intToStr(test_value) << "bar";
std::cout << "test: " << val.str() << std::endl;
```

Does anyone have some ideas?

Thanks

Comment: which compiler, OS etc? btw, this is not "casting", but reading (the `<<` operator of `stringstream` is inherited from `ostream`)

Comment: Terminology: a **cast** is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to **convert** something from one type to another. A **conversion** occurs when the compiler changes the type of something from one type to another. A conversion is **explicit** if there's a cast that tells the compiler to do it; otherwise, it's **implicit**. The code above has no casts, so any conversions are implicit.

Comment: The OS is Lion 10.7.4 and the compiler is the "Apple LLVM compiler 3.1"